# variable factors in Simulimk

Tags: control-system, matlab, simulink

In my simulation of **Van der Pol** equation in matlab, I need to have variable factors the same as shown in following picture but Simulink doesn't accept that. how I can solve this problem?

[image: simulation of van der pol equation]

Comment: Do they need to change during a simulation or you just need to change them

Comment: @JonRB: I need to simulate the equation and I think they they should change during a simulation?

Comment: @JonRB:what is the prevalent way for simulation of these types equations because I just get started ?

Comment: Do you want to change them while the simulation is running? if yes... Do you want to change them based on the state x or based on what exactly? or you want to give them as time series?.

Comment: Have you defined \$k\$, \$c\$ and \$m\$ in an m.file? If you need to change them during simulation, then you should use a product block and use some time-dependent signal to generate the behaviour that you desire.